# Jquery Click send doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Hi everyone i have one question about jquery click send function. I have created this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mustafaozturk74/zr2r1vyz/1/) from jsfiddle. So if you visit the demo then you can see there is one smiley and textarea. When you write some text and press enter then the message sending successfully. But i want to add also when you click the smiley then it need to send `(w1)` from the image `sticker="(w1)"` like click to send. But click send function doesn't work. What is the problem on there and what is the solution ? Anyone can help me in this regard ?

**JS**

```
$('.sendcomment').bind('keydown', function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        var ID = $(this).attr("data-msgid");
        var comment = $(this).val();

        if ($.trim(comment).length == 0) {
            $("#commentload" + ID).text("Plese write your comment!");
        } else {
            $("#commentload" + ID).text(comment);
            $("#commentid" + ID).val('').css("height", "35px").focus();
        }
    }
});
/**/
$(document).ready(function() {
$('body').on("click",'.emo', function() {

        var ID = $(this).attr("data-msgid");
        var comment = $(this).val();

        if ($.trim(comment).length == 0) {
            $("#commentload" + ID).text("nothing!");
        } else {
            $("#commentload" + ID).text(comment);
            $("#commentid" + ID).val('').css("height", "35px").focus();
        }

 });
});
    $('body').on('click', '.sm-sticker', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var theComment = $(this).parents('.container').find('.sendcomment');
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        var sticker = $(this).attr('sticker');
        var msg = jQuery.trim(theComment.val());

        if(msg == ''){
            var sp = '';
        } else {
            var sp = ' ';
        }

        theComment.val(jQuery.trim(msg + sp + sticker + sp));
    });
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="container one">
 <div class="comments-area" id="commentload47">comments will be come here</div>
 <div class="user-post" id="postbody47">
    <textarea class="sendcomment" name="comment" id="commentid47" data-msgid="47"></textarea>
    <div class="stiemo">
     <img src="http://d.lanrentuku.com/down/png/1009/networking/emoticon_inlove.png" class="sm-sticker emo" sticker="(w1)"> click smiley to send (w1)</div>
   </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @TomSlick press enter working fine. But if you click smiley then it is not sending.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/zr2r1vyz/2/ wrong selector - you need .sendcomment attribute....

Comment: @TomSlick which browser you are using. I tested it all browser but didn't worked for me.

Comment: @nevermind your code is ok but when you click the smiley then the result is (nothing) it means no sended (w1)

Comment: are you trying this http://jsfiddle.net/zr2r1vyz/3/??

Comment: @Sushil `(w1)` need to send the smiley is submit button also . When you click smiley then the `(w1)` will come in textarea and at the same time the smiley also is submit button.

Comment: what about this http://jsfiddle.net/zr2r1vyz/5/?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this :

just append below JS after the line `theComment.val(jQuery.trim(msg + sp + sticker + sp));`

```
var e = $.Event("keydown");
e.keyCode = 13; // # Some key code value
$('.sendcomment').trigger(e);
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ucscwew1/)

Comment: This is really best answer very clean. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

you should use this:

```
$('body').on("click",'.emo', function() {

    var ID = $('.sendcomment').attr("data-msgid");
    var comment = $('.sendcomment').val();

    if ($.trim(comment).length == 0) {
        $("#commentload" + ID).text("nothing!");
    } else {
        $("#commentload" + ID).text(comment);
        $("#commentid" + ID).val('').css("height", "35px").focus();
    }

});
```

so basically instead of this you have to use input and get msgid and val from there, use same approach for rest.
So when you are attaching event on some button and you want to use data from some other dom element you have to get that element by using $(selector) under your delegated function, really simple approach.

Comment: did you see that they said nothing. It means no sended message.

Comment: if I type text and press smiley I see my text above same as if I press enter.

Comment: you are right but i want also when you click smiley then it need to send (w1) but it said nothing. Nothing means message not sended.

Comment: check this out http://jsfiddle.net/zr2r1vyz/4/ basically if you do not type message and pres on smiley then you have to cover that case and send sticker instead of nothing. With this info you may fix rest of code, right?